# Label LodLive predicate edges with rdfs:labels, not URIs

Tags: javascript, sparql

I have deployed [LodLive](http://en.lodlive.it/) to one of my servers.  I really like it for interactively visualizing RDF data sets.  I would like to make one modification, but I'm struggling with the JavaScript.

LodLive represents entities (subjects and URI objects) as circles.  Lines between entities represent the predicate (or verb) in the relationship.  It appears to me that LodLive constructs the edge labels with the right-hand portion of the predicate URIs.

Querying [dbpedia](https://dbpedia.org/sparql) for the relationship between Barrack Obama and Joe Biden gives:

```
select * where
{ <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Barack_Obama> ?p <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Joe_Biden> }

p
http://dbpedia.org/ontology/vicePresident
http://dbpedia.org/property/vicepresident
```

And that's what you see in the LodLive visualization:

[image]

My triples mostly use classes from OBO foundry ontologies.  [OBO predicates](http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000100) typically have labels, but the right hand portion of their URIs are codes:

```
select distinct * where
{ <http://purl.obolibrary.org/obo/IAO_0000114> rdfs:label ?lab .
filter(lang(?lab) = 'en') }

=> "has curation status"@en
```

[image]

How can I label the LodLive edges with the labels of the predicates they depict?

The [project](https://github.com/dvcama/LodLive) is on github. I think I've traced this to a `standardLine` function in `lodlive.core.js` that takes a label argument.  It's called in turn by `processDraw`, which says

```
label = canvas.attr("data-propertyName-" + toId);
```

And then splits label on `/` characters and basically keeps the last slice.

There's a `drawaLine` function which appears to tie into that

```
aCanvas.attr("data-propertyName-" + to.attr("id"), propertyName);
```

And an `addNewDoc` function

```
addNewDoc : function(obj, ele, callback)
```

that seems to set propertyName

```
var propertyName = ele.attr("data-property");
```

I believe the only place `addNewDoc` is called is in function `addClick`, like this:

```
methods.addNewDoc(obj, $(this));
```

I don't get what `ele` is within the context of `addNewDoc`, or what `$(this)` is within `addClick`

Comment: Mark, LodLive now supports what you need just before drawing the arc https://github.com/dvcama/LodLive/commit/e90f5887cdec2bf347597c33653504cdf4e4e01f#diff-42a33e4d979032d95670991ab4aac0fbR1455 lodlive looks for a translation of the property
https://github.com/dvcama/LodLive/commit/e90f5887cdec2bf347597c33653504cdf4e4e01f#diff-c581bc3b8848a511ffba905308c6ccfdR570 just clone the code and add the labels you need

Comment: Great.  Will test and reply soon.

Comment: After creating a labeler block in the lodlive.properties.js file, my edges have nice human-readable edges.  Thanks.